# Differentiability of the Schatten $p$-norm on positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, reference-request, positive-semidefinite

Let $V$ be the vector space of symmetric matrices in $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$. For $p\in (1,\infty)$, the Schatten $p$-norm of $M\in V$ is defined as $\|M\|_p =(\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(M)^p)^{1/p}$ where $\sigma_1(M),\ldots,\sigma_n(M)$ are the singular values of $M$. Now, let $C\subset V$ be the cone of positive semi-definite matrices. It follows from [this old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567399/derivative-of-schatten-p-norm) that 
$$\nabla \|M\|_p = \|M\|_p^{1-p}M^{p-1}\qquad \forall M\in C.$$

> Where is a reference for the above statement?

Comment: As the deadline approach, I should say that I am even fine with just a citable reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M\in C$. Then $M$ is positive semi-definite, thus $|M|=M$ and
$$\|M\|_p = \big(\operatorname{tr}M^p\big)^\frac 1p.$$
A scalar-by-matrix derivative using the chain rule gives
$$\frac{\partial\;\;}{\partial M}\,\|M\|_p
 \:=\:\left.\frac{d\;}{dx}x^\frac 1p\right|_{x\,=\,\operatorname{tr}M^p}
\cdot\frac{\partial\;\;}{\partial M}\,\operatorname{tr}M^p \\[3ex]
 \qquad\quad=\:\frac 1p\big(\operatorname{tr}M^p\big)^{\frac 1p-1}\cdot pM^{p-1} \\[3ex]
 =\:\|M\|_p^{1-p}M^{p-1}$$
This is a straightforward application of matrix calculus, and might be the reason why there is no quick $W^3$ hit for this derivation.

A general and helpful reference is [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities) .
For the derivative of $\,\operatorname{tr}(M^p)\,$ in the second term you may also look at [page 155 here](https://mason.gmu.edu/~jgentle/csi771/13f/matrixcalculus.pdf) .

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is pretty much what I am looking for. What is a "quick $W^3$ hit"?

Comment: Sounds good $+\;\ddot\smile\quad W^3 = WWW$